# jquery insertAfter() inserts clone too

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a strange thing happening in my js script.

When the click function is executed, one element is supposed to be **inserted below** another one, **but for some reason, the elements clone is inserted there as well**.

How come? The cloning is happening outside the click function.

Pls help me understand what is going on.

http://jsbin.com/unenil/1/edit

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".one").insertAfter(".two");
  $(".status").text("done");
});


var clone_one = $(".one").clone();
var clone_two = $(".two").clone();
$("body").append(clone_one);
$("body").append(clone_two);
```

Basically I dont understand why the click function in this case has anything to do with the cloning which takes place outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloned element has the `one` class, so his clone too.

Therefore `$(".one")` contains both the cloned and the clone.

A solution would be to keep a reference to the original element and to insert it :

```
var original = $(".one");
var clone_one = original.clone();
var clone_two = $(".two").clone();
$("body").append(clone_one);
$("body").append(clone_two);

$("button").click(function() {
  original.insertAfter(".two");
  $(".status").text("done");
});
```

Comment: wouldnt it be the same? both still have the same class. I was thinking using remove/addclass to distinguish them from each other.